# How I setup a background limit in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a page with a searchable table, when someone use the text box to search for data the jQuery code will give live results "like google search suggestion" but inside the table itself.

When there is no text inside the search text box, the table show all data inside it. and the background work great on that, no matter how long the page is.

My problem is when someone search on specific thing and the table only show a few data like "1 or two" the background crop and a blank white background appear in the footer.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    background: url(https://example.com/how/900.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #000000;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's because you have given height auto, and it will adjust to the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this as the first rule in your stylesheet

```
{
    html, body{ height:100%; }
}
```

Remove `height: auto;` from you `body` selector.

---

Since you did not "[reset](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/)" your styles, the browser is using the default one, and sadly the default style for the body does not render it as at least the full height as the viewport allows

Comment: It's still the same problem! I change it, It works if I setup the hehight to 150% , but the page become so long!

Comment: Now it works for some reson after a cleared the bouwser history it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `height: auto` to `height: 100vh` will resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: can you share link for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: Working fine not facing any issue.

Comment: write four "ffff" only on firefox, I just noticed that

Comment: Can you share the link?